# Check if two files exist, then if they do, run batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch script that checks for two files on the root of the C: (`C:\file1` and `C:\file`). If they exist then another batch file should execute (that will install some software). I thought something along the lines of the below would work:

```
IF EXIST “c:\file1.txt” AND "c:\file2.txt"
msiexec /I "\\SERVER...\application.msi
```

However, I am struggling to get what I want to work.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Before posting questions about how to use a command, it may help you if you read the help file for the command itself.  The `IF` command does not have any `AND` or `OR` options.  You can read the help file for any command by opening a command prompt and typing the the command name followed by a forward slash and question mark. `if /?`

Comment: Make sure that you do not use smart quotes, as used in your example code, when you create your batch file.

Comment: For the correct syntax of the `if` command, type `if /?` into a command prompt and read the output very carefully; as you can see you cannot place line-breaks as you did. Furthermore, there are no keywords `and`/`or` keywords; however, you could nest two `if` statements instead (just as a hint)...

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys. Gerhard's command was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the first, then the next, if the first does not match, it will not attempt the second, if it does it will attempt the second but not run the command if second file not found:

```
if exist "c:\file1.txt" if exist "c:\file2.txt" msiexec /I "\SERVER...\application.msi"
```

Comment: Apologies for the late reply but this was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for your help.